# Java parse plist file

Tags: java, arrays, configuration, plist

I need to read a `.plist` file in `Java` and extract information from it. 
I found a solution on stackoverflow ([This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484163/how-to-parse-plist-file-in-java)) and adjusted it to Commons Configuration 2.x. 
My code:

```
public void parsePlist(File f) throws ConfigurationException, FileNotFoundException {
        XMLPropertyListConfiguration plist = new XMLPropertyListConfiguration();
        // load plist from classoath
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        plist.read(br);
        Iterator<String> keys = plist.getKeys("dictionary");
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            // do someting with the value
            System.out.println(plist.getString(keys.next()));
        }

    }
```

The file f is the `.plist` file.
Now  the file is structured as:

```
<key>dictionary</key>
         <array>
         <dict>
             <key>key1</key>
             <string>value1</string>
             <key>key2</key>
             <string>value2</string>
             <key>key3</key>
             <string>value3</string>
         </dict>
        </array>
```

And when I'm trying to get the content of the key "dictionnary" the result is **null**. When the `<array>` is deleted it works fine. 
This is part of a testfile I wrote and I could simply remove the `<array>` but the file I'm intended to parse this part can't be removed. 
What does I have to do to get into the `array`?

Comment: Well, if it doesn't appear to be doing anything, run it in the debugger and go through step by step. (Or just run through line by line with print statements...)

Comment: Yeah you're right, I was blind af, but I faced a new problem and changed my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look for 'dict' insteed of 'dictionary'.